# jQuery: Refreshing an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this accordion-like script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".content").hide();
    jQuery(".heading").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500)
    });
});
```

But then I add this line in order to reload the element after the content div toggles...

```
document.getElementsByClassName(transition current).reload();
```

and as a result, the accordion no longer works... The `content` class is always being displayed.

Why is this line affecting the behavior of the accordion?

I'm trying to refresh the element while retaining the accordion style divs...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the isotype jQuery plugin, so the issue was resolved by adding this one line as a callback to "relayout" any changes that were loaded into the DOM.

```
   $('#blog-list').isotope('reLayout');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation since the elements are created dynamically

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(document).on('click', ".heading", function () {
        $(this).next(".content").stop(true, true).slideToggle(500)
    });
});
```

*Still you might have a problem of all `content` element getting displayed once the element is reloaded, for hiding those elements you need to use any load callback system provided by the reloader you are using*

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... Can you please provide more info?

Comment: @shmuli what is the library used to reload the element

Answer (score 0):

You've got a syntax error here:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(transition current).reload();
```

`getElementsByClassName` expects a string to be passed (not to mention that the above isn't syntactically correct even if it did expect two arguments).  You're trying to pass two variables (which you haven't defined).  Pass a string:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('transition current').reload();
```

Blast.  That doesn't work either!  Reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) informs us that `getElementsByClassName` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which doesn't have the method `reload()`, resulting in another error.  Are you even *looking* at the console?

You may be assuming that `getElementsByClassName` returns a jQuery object, in which case you can replace the above with `$('.transistion, .current').reload();`

Again, let's note that `reload()` isn't a native jQuery method either.  I'm assuming you're bringing it in via a plugin.  If I'm wrong, comment below and I'll update the answer.